# Angular multicomponent radio

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a project in `Angular` and wanted to include an online radio that works after exiting the component that controls it, so I made something like this:

`<a (click)=playById(3)><img class="radiostation_small" src="../../assets/radiostations/zlote_radiostation.png" alt="rmf_fm"></a>`.

That's my button-like element to select the radiostation and play music, to do that I wrote simple function looking like this:

```
  {
    // tslint:disable: deprecation
    if (isUndefined(this.audio))
    {
      this.audio = new Audio();
      this.audio.src = this.srcs[id];
      this.audio.load();
      this.audio.play();
      this.dir_name = this.names[id];
      this.dir_desc = this.descs[id];
    }
    else if (!isUndefined(this.audio))
    {
      this.audio.src = this.srcs[id];
      this.audio.load();
      this.audio.play();
      this.dir_name = this.names[id];
      this.dir_desc = this.descs[id];
    }
  }
```

And here is my problem: **After Exit into the main component and enter back into it, I can double audio**, I mean when I choose another radio station, the old one is still playing in the background no matter what I tried.

I think it's because when entering the radio component again, the audio object can be duplicated.

And here a question arises for you, do you know any way that the radio component can control the music being played, and that it is not duplicated, and that the music plays in the entire application?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't use an Angular Service? This would allow you to manage the audio via a singleton.  https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: The more reason is that I don't know how to apply it to make it work here (intern experience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow-up to comments on the question, you could use a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) to manage the audio. You could structure that service somewhat like the one below:

audio.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AudioService {

    private readonly audio: HTMLAudioElement = new Audio();

    public DirName: string;
    public DirDesc: string;

    constructor() { }

    public PlayAudio(id: any, srcs: Array<any>, names: Array<any>, descs: Array<any>) {
        this.audio.src = srcs[id];
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
        this.DirName = names[id];
        this.DirDesc = descs[id];
    }    
}
```

To consume the service, just set up a component's constructor to request that dependency from the injector(s).

random-component.ts

```js
export class RandomComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private readonly audio: AudioService) { 
        //
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        // 
    }    
}
```

You'll probably want to add some methods to the service that allow the desired level of control over the audio.